# Si on ne sort pas un importun de force ou en faisant appel à la force, on le fait sortir…?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Je cherche une façon de dire à une collègue que je vais faire sortir un malfaiteur agressif qui refuse de sortir d’un établissement après la fermeture sans l’usage de la force, et cela malgré l’entêtement de l’importun.

Idées qui me viennent en tête:

> Je vais appréhender gentiment l’importun pour le mettre dehors.

> Je vais tenter par la persuasion ou en faisant preuve de psychologie de le mettre dehors sans devoir en venir aux mains ou sans faire appel à la force.

Je suis ouvert aux reformulations!

Comment: *Malfaiteur* « Celui qui commet des délits, des crimes » dans un établissement, non seulement il y a un problème judiciaire, mais un risque d'arrêt de travail qui ne sera pas trop apprécié par le patron … il y a une reformulation à voir pour que la question soit crédible

Comment: @Personne Eh bien dans la situation que je cherche à décrire, les policiers ont dû intervenir pour faire sortir l’importun car il devenait de plus en plus agressif, il a même levé la main sur moi et sur ma collègue. Quand on doit faire appel à l’autorité, il me semble qu’on puisse qualifier un importun de malfaiteur.

Comment: @Personne J’ai mis la question à jour pour indiquer que l’importun en question était agressif et n’hésitait pas à recourir à la violence.

Comment: Il persévérait dans son refus, j’imagine qu’il vivait un épisode psychotique.

Comment: Je n’arrive pas à voir en quoi la question n’est pas crédible…

Comment: Il y a danger, vous avez dû faire intervenir la police, les bonnes intentions, les paroles bienveillantes ne peuvent rien contre une personne réellement dangereuse, quel que soit son état psychique… et le vôtre. « J'avais envie d'intervenir pour mettre dehors en douceur cette personne agitée, mais j'ai été obligé d'appeler la police devant sa détermination agressive à rester dans l'établissement où elle pouvait blesser des collègues » … à moins que vous ayez des compétences en maintien de l'ordre et self défense !

Comment: Voilà je ne pouvais user de force étant donné que n’ai pas les permis requis par la loi!

Comment: *Câlice de crisse, je vais te me le fout' dehors !* ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre lol 

Comment: @jlliagre — Sous d'autres cieux : D'une voix forte et percutante  « Ho là » puis, d'une voix douce, murmurante et presque câline, inaudible pour les autres, avec le sourire chinois n°7 du 3ᵉ dan de karaté : « Tu t'casses ou j'te fais bouffer tes c… » … à Pretzel de donner une suite à tant de gentillesse !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Je vais convaincre la personne de sortir

> Je vais faire en sorte que la personne sorte de son plein gré